# Fluent Assertions target framework

Tags: fluent-assertions, target-framework

I had installed Fluent Assertions v.3 on the unit tests project and all was good until i had to update it to v.5.
After that i get:

> Obj does not contain a definition for 'ShouldBeEquivalentTo' and no
>   extension method 'ShouldBeEquivalentTo' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Obj ' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I have seen on https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions it needs .NET 4.5 and i set this on packages.config:

```
 <package id="FluentAssertions" version="5.0.0" **targetFramework="net45"** />
```

and on csproj as follow:

```
<Reference Include="FluentAssertions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=33f2691a05b67b6a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">      <HintPath>..\packages\FluentAssertions.5.0.0\lib\net45\FluentAssertions.dll</HintPath> </Reference>
```

But i still got the same error. What i am doing wrong?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If `Obj` implements `IComparable<T>` it's probably [this issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/755) which has been fixed in the source.

Can you provide an example of the test, that no longer compiles?

Comment: @JakeManet Fluent Assertions 5.1.1 has just been released with the fix.